# What's the C# equivalent to the With statement in VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalence of “With…End With” in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063429/equivalence-of-with-end-with-in-c)

There was one feature of VB that I really like...the `With` statement. Does C# have any equivalent to it? I know you can use `using` to not have to type a namespace, but it is limited to just that. In VB you could do this:

```
With Stuff.Elements.Foo
    .Name = "Bob Dylan"
    .Age = 68
    .Location = "On Tour"
    .IsCool = True
End With
```

The same code in C# would be:

```
Stuff.Elements.Foo.Name = "Bob Dylan";
Stuff.Elements.Foo.Age = 68;
Stuff.Elements.Foo.Location = "On Tour";
Stuff.Elements.Foo.IsCool = true;
```

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063429/equivalence-of-with-end-with-in-c

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Not really, you have to assign a variable. So

```
    var bar = Stuff.Elements.Foo;
    bar.Name = "Bob Dylan";
    bar.Age = 68;
    bar.Location = "On Tour";
    bar.IsCool = True;
```

Or in C# 3.0 and above:

```
    var bar = new FooType
    {
        Name = "Bob Dylan",
        Age = 68,
        Location = "On Tour",
        IsCool = True
    };

    Stuff.Elements.Foo = bar;
```

Comment: You are treating 'Stuff.Elements.Foo' as a type.  Is that how it is being used in the VB code, or is it actually a reference to a nested variable?  The technique is perfectly valid but I think your code isn't quite right.

Comment: I wrote a [blog](http://blog.baltrinic.com/software-development/dotnet/c-equivalent-for-visual-basic-with-statement) some time back on how to simulate a with statement in c# using extension methods and lambda expressions.

Comment: @Kenneth: That's pretty clever, although it could be argued that `Object.Child.Grandchild.GreatGrandchild.Property1 = 1;` violates the Law of Demeter.

Comment: @Robert, _maybe_ but that's a topic for another thread.

Comment: The seconds part of this answer is invalid, `Stuff.Elements.Foo` is a variable. If it's a type - then you're missing `new`

Comment: "Not really". Actually not at all. That is different and only works in initialisers. The VB version was more commonly used with objects already instantiated.

Answer (score 9):

Aside from object initializers (usable only in constructor calls), the best you can get is:

```
var it = Stuff.Elements.Foo;
it.Name = "Bob Dylan";
it.Age = 68;
...
```

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing in C# 3.0, is that you can use a constructor to initialize properties:

```
Stuff.Elements.Foo foo = new Stuff.Elements.Foo() {Name = "Bob Dylan", Age = 68, Location = "On Tour", IsCool = true}
```

Comment: You are treating 'Stuff.Elements.Foo' as a type. Is that how it is being used in the VB code, or is it actually a reference to a nested variable? The technique is perfectly valid but I think your code isn't quite right. (I've copied quark's comment here as it applies to this answer too)