# c# Output WinForm to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, office-interop

Have researched outputting to Excel and can successfully do so.  My question is more if I am missing something simpler.

Currently, if I want to set the font, cell color, size, etc. of a single cell, I am doing so like this:

```
        range = (Range)ws.Cells[10, 12];
        range.Formula = "=SUM(R10C10:R10C11)";
        range.Calculate();
        range.Font.Bold = true;
        range.Font.Underline = true;
        range.Style = wb.Styles["Currency"];
        range.Font.Color = Color.Red;
        range.Font.Name = "Arial";
        range.Font.Size = 26;
        borders = range.Borders;
        borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        borders.Weight = 2d;
```

Did I miss something in the documentation that allows me to do this on a SINGLE cell without having to create a `Range`?

Comment: And what is wrong in using range?

Comment: Nothing is "wrong" with doing it this way, I was just wondering if I was just adding extra steps that I did not need.

Comment: Nope. Abstractions always takes some extra steps in simple usages but provide much more functionality in complex cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, C# requires an object qualifier (see [What's the C# equivalent to the With statement in VB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175334/whats-the-c-sharp-equivalent-to-the-with-statement-in-vb). So your current code is to protocol.