# Code equivalence in C# and Visual Basic and VB code structure

Tags: c#, vb.net, with-statement

I am fairly new to C# and VB coding. I need to create .Net framework describing chemical reaction as an extension so that I can reuse it in HYSYS. There are tutorials from 2004 which has a tutorial implementation in VB. I was trying to convert the structure from VB to C# but I am confused at `With....End With` implementation. Can you describe whats going on here as there is no assignment relations?

Ref Code lines is below and the tutorial pdf link is https://sites.ualberta.ca/CMENG/che312/F06ChE416/HysysDocs/AspenHYSYSCustomizationGuide.pdf (chapter 3).

```vb
With hyContainer
    .SetReactionPropertyState rpReactants, vsCalculated
    .SetReactionPropertyState rpStoichiometricCoefficients, vsCalculated
    .SetReactionPropertyState rpMinTemperature, vsCalculated
    .SetReactionPropertyState rpMaxTemperature, vsCalculated
    .SetReactionPropertyState rpReactionBasis, vsCalculated
    .SetReactionPropertyState rpReactionPhase, vsCalculated
    .SetReactionPropertyState rpBaseReactant, vsCalculated
    .SetReactionPropertyState rpBasisConversion, vsCalculated
    .SetReactionPropertyState rpRateConversion, vsCalculated
End With
```

Comment: My questions is what ".SetReactionPropertyState rpReactants, vsCalculated" does this mean? It does not seem like an assignment. Is it defining new properties of the object?

Comment: With no parentheses around the arguments, that code looks more like VBA than VB.NET.

Comment: @UmeshPandey parentheses are optional

Comment: @UmeshPandey If you follow the duplicate link which shows you the [equivalent C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1175335/11683), does that not tell you what it does?

Comment: @GSerg to be fair, the code in your link isn't equivalent to his code. The code in your link constructs a class, and then assigns its properties (which you can do with an object initializer in C#). This code is calling a bunch of methods on an object (which you cannot do with an object initializer in C#).

Comment: Thanks all for the quick responses. As I am new in both C# and VB, lack of parentheses and use of space got me confused. The answer by canton7 illustrates that pretty much. Anyway, since I am more from MATLAB and Python background, having space and no parentheses did not make any sense to me. Thanks once again to all.

Comment: @canton7 Use the part that is above the `Or in C# 3.0:` line.

Comment: @GSerg still, that's assigning a property rather than calling a method. Given that he didn't know that his VB was calling methods, that could be confusing.

Comment: @the_lotus Parentheses are optional only when there are no arguments. When there are, presence or absence of parentheses [is significant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/11683), and inserting them where there should not be any is a [compile time error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15040060/11683). All that is given the OP's code is actually VB6/VBA, which it evidently is; in VB.NET the rules [are different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/sub-statement#calling-a-sub-procedure).

Comment: Anyway, I implemented like canton7 suggested, which I believe is calling a method rather than assigning property. It seems that I will get building error with error code "The name 'vsCalculated' does not exist in the current context". In the demo program written in VB, they do not define 'vsCalculated' anywhere. So does it make any sense that it is calling the method?

Comment: @UmeshPandey It makes sense because calling a method has nothing to do with whether a variable is declared. If it is not declared in the code itself, then there must be a reference to a library that declares it.

Comment: `vsCalculated` should be coming from the type library.  In this case, it's a member of `VariableStatus_enum`; depending on which version of Visual Studio you use, it may give you a light bulb option to add the appropriate namespace prefix or `using` / `Imports` statement.  Similarly, the "rp" prefixed items are also enum members, `ReactionProperty_enum`, and will need similar handling.

Comment: It should be coming from HYSYS reference but when I tried to compile it I could not compile. I might need to specify using statement but I really do not have any idea what kind of library is associated with HYSYS. Anyway thanks all for the support. I got chance to learn a lot of useful coding tips here.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent C# is:

```
hyContainer.SetReactionPropertyState(rpReactants, vsCalculated);
hyContainer.SetReactionPropertyState(rpStoichiometricCoefficients, vsCalculated);
// etc
```

C# doesn't have an equivalent of `with`.

Comment: I was stuck in this line and I guess I will face many more problems. Thanks for this one.