# Is there a VB.NET "With" statement in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalence of “With…End With” in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063429)

So I don't know if this question has been asked before and I am not a big fan of [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). But one syntax that I am missing in C# is the `With` syntax.

In VB.NET you can write:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
With sb
    .Append("foo")
    .Append("bar")
    .Append("zap")
End With
```

Is there a syntax in C# that I have missed that does the same thing?

Comment: It it really much better to write that instead of `sb.Append("foo")`?? I'm programming for 12 years in VB.NET and have never understood the benefit of the with statement. Just another thing you must lookup everytime(What was that again?)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I wonder the same thing. I code in VB.NET for the last 4 years maybe, and have never found a use for the With statement, except for the New...With construct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there isn't.

This was intentionally left out of C#, as it doesn't add much convenience, and because it can easily be used to write confusing code.

Blog post from Scott Wiltamuth, Group Program Manager for Visual C#, about the with keyword: https://web.archive.org/web/20111217005440/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336816.aspx

For the special case of a `StringBuilder`, you can chain the calls:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
  .Append("foo")
  .Append("bar")
  .Append("zap");
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you provide an example about a confusing VB.Net code that uses With/End With?

Comment: you might also note that C# has the object initializer syntax, but it can only be used to set public instance variables, not make function calls.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct analogue to the VB `With` statement.

However, note that `StringBuilder.Append` returns the `StringBuilder` instance, so the following code is equivalent to your original:

```
sb.Append("foo").Append("bar").Append("zap");
```

or even

```
sb.Append("foo")
  .Append("bar")
  .Append("zap");
```

This is not possible for all objects/methods, though.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no equivalent syntax.

`With` is VB/VB.NET only.

Answer (score 2):

There is an equivalent for `New Type With`:

```
var obj = new Type {
    PropName = Value,
    PropName = Value
};
```

, but not for the common `With`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't - this is Visual Basic-only.

One of the prime reasons it was left out of C# was that it can lead to confusing code, for example when using nested `With` statements.

Comment: The link appears to be broken

Comment: The links appears to be (effectively) broken - it redirects to a non-specific page.