# How to avoid typing the object name for each property?

Tags: c#

`Class1` is a class object which is already instantiated. Is there any alternative approach not to type every time `Class1.`?

```
Class1.Hostname = location.Ip;
Class1.UserName = location.Username;
Class1.Password = location.Password;
Class1.Port = 23;
Class1.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = true;
Class1.LogPath = "";
Class1.IsDebug = true;
Class1.Downloadwaitmiliseconds = 1000;
```

Comment: You can read about object initializers in C# ...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Comment: He said that Class1 is already instantiated.

Comment: If it's already instantiated you can't really get around it in C#. You _could_ create a [fluent API](https://scottlilly.com/how-to-create-a-fluent-interface-in-c/). It depends on how much code you want to add to "simplify" this.

Comment: iirc in visual basic there was a way to do a `using ()` or `with` type statement but I can't remember what it was, or if it carried over in any form to c#

Comment: @NibblyPig you're looking for the keyword [`With`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)

Comment: Check [the third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5964848/4934172) to the duplicate question.

Comment: @Default That's only for VB. There's no C# equivalent by default.

Comment: It's a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate... some research should be done before asking a question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled To be fair to the OP, all these duplicates are hard to find if you're not familiar with VB's `With` statement.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed which is exactly the reason why I didn't downvote the question :-)

Comment: So no possible as i see

Comment: @abc Not by default but you can create an extension method and use it somewhat similar to the `With` statement in VB. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5964848/4934172) provides an example on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```cs
Class1 = new Class() 
{ 
  Hostname = location.Ip;
  UserName = location.Username;
  Password = location.Password;
  Port = 23;
  GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = true;
  LogPath = "";
  IsDebug = true;
  Downloadwaitmiliseconds = 1000;

  AlreadySetPropety1 = Class1.AlreadySetPropety1;
  AlreadySetPropety2 = Class1.AlreadySetPropety2;
  …
}
```

That means that along your properties you have to set already set properties but in fact there is not issue in your code. You can refactor it to some method for instance if you don’t like personally.

Comment: this is new instansiation and i am aware about this.

Comment: You got me.Switch to VB as noted by moderators. Check also https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/call-a-function-of-visual-basic-into-C-Sharp-page/.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the properties after instantiation, you can create a method that takes those as values as arguments and set them inside the method, where you would not need the variable name. 
Like a Fill method. Same as what you may do in the constructor of the class.

If you are able to do this during the instantiation you can do something like

```
var Class1= new YOURCLASS{
    Hostname = location.Ip;
    UserName = location.Username;
    Password = location.Password;
    Port = 23;
    GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = true;
    LogPath = "";
    IsDebug = true;
    Downloadwaitmiliseconds = 1000;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might add into your `Class1` a set method, like:

```
class Class1 {
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public bool GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey { get; set; }
    public string LogPath { get; set; }
    public bool IsDebug { get; set }
    public int Downloadwaitmiliseconds { get; set; }

    public void setValues(string hostname, string username, string password, int port /* adding other values*/) 
    {
        Hostname = hostname;
        Username = username
        Port = port;
        /* The other values */
    }

}
```

Maybe is the way to do it if you have the object initialized

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax that I am aware of to do that. You might be able to write a Setter along the lines of:

```
public void Set(hostname = null, username = null, password = null)
{
    if (hostname != null)
        Hostname = hostname;
    if (username != null)
        Username = username ;
    ...
}
```

and you can call it with explicit parameters:

```
Class1.Set(hostname="localhost", username="me")
```

Of course this only works when `null` is not a valid option for your properties