# VBA to C# with statement

Tags: c#, vba, excel-dna

I am trying to convert simple vba "with statemnt" to C#. ProductRangeA and B are named ranges. Could someone to give a hint?

```
With ProductRangeA
   myRow= .Rows.Count: 
   myValue= .Value  
End With

With ProductRangeB
   myRow= .Columns.Count: 
   myValue= .Value  
End With
```

Comment: there's no equivalent in C#. You can achieve a similar syntax with some `Action<T>` based code.

Comment: @HighCore I can't think of how you would approximate it with `Action<T>` -- can you post an example?

Comment: Hi I am looking at same functionality, meaning that the syntax could be differrent. thanks

Comment: Check this link, there are several similar methods:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481725/with-block-equivalent-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HighCore said, there's no C# equivalent to VB's `With` block.  Here's the equivalent C# code:

```
myRow = ProductRangeA.Rows.Count;
myValue = ProductRangeA.Value;

myRow = ProductRangeB.Columns.Count;
myValue = ProductRangeB.Value;
```

Since you can't avoid typing ProductRangeA and ProductRangeB twice each, you can reduce typing by using shorter variable names.  That can make the code more difficult to understand, of course.