# C# : Setting the properties of an object in a single block

Tags: c#, syntax, object-properties

Is a way to set the properties of an object in a block using C#, similar to how you write an object initializer?

For example:

```
Button x = new Button(){
    Text = "Button",
    BackColor = Color.White
};
```

Is there a syntax similar to this that can be properties after the object has been created?

For example:

```
Button x = new Button();
x{
   Text = "Button",
   BackColor = Color.White
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With block equivalent in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481725/with-block-equivalent-in-c)

Comment: This is called an [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) and can only be used when `new`ing an object. Your second piece of code is simply not valid C#.

Comment: Thanks - Pieter Witvoet.You gave me the answer I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form

```
Button x = new Button(){
    Text = "Button",
    BackColor = Color.White
};
```

Is part of the syntax for constructors and constructors only. You can't use the same syntax on the next line. You can leave out the `()`, though, and use a `var` for the variable type, to give you the more compact;

```
var x = new Button{
    Text = "Button",
    BackColor = Color.White
};
```

After construction, the only way to update it is through normal assignment operations;

```
x.Text = "Button";
```

Comment: Thanks. You gave me the answer I want : "Is part of.."

Comment: click on that grey tick for me? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this; say you have a class named Platypus.

Your grandfather's way:

```
Platypus p = new Platypus();
p.CWeek = "1";
p.CompanyName = "Pies from Pablo";
p.PADescription = "Pennsylvania is the Keystone state (think cops)";
```

The newfangled way:

```
Platypus p = new Platypus
{
    CWeek = "1",
    CompanyName = "Pies from Pablo",
    PADescription = "Pennsylvania is the Keystone state (think cops)"
};
```

Comment: this has to be the most random example code I have seen. Way to be creative

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. He's asking for a special syntax for setting properties ***after*** the object is already created.

Comment: The one who understands best what I want to tell -sstan, thanks. I got my answer. There is no indication in the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want it?

```
Button x = new Button();
x.Text = "Button";
x.BackColor = Color.White;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with property initializers.

```
Button x = new Button { Text = "Button", BackColor = Color.White };
```

Comment: This is identical to the first listing in the question. OP's asking for the ability to do this on the instance itself once it has been created.