# VBA change font properties of chart axes without using With-EndWith Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am running an Excel macro in a C# program. 
I have a chart and I'd like to change its properties.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("myChart").Activate
ActiveChart.Axe(xlCategory).Select

With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font  'Run-Time error: method of object failed 
     .BaselineOffset = 0
     .Bold = msoTrue
     .Size = 12
     .Italic = msoFalse
End With
```

However using the With-EndWith statemnt is giving me a run-time error.
Therefore, I'd like to know if there is any code that is equivalent to the code above. I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: Do you know what `With End With` does?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481725/with-block-equivalent-in-c

Comment: It's not clear whether you are running this in VBA or trying to translate it to C#

Answer (score 2):

if your goal is to simply change `TickLabels` font,  may try something like this

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("myChart").Activate
Dim Axx As Axis
Set Axx = ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory)
With Axx.TickLabels.Font
     .Bold = True
     .Size = 12
     .Name = "Bookman Old Style"
     .Italic = False
     .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
```